# squid режем скорость авторизованным пользователям

Tags: squid

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать авторизацию по логину и паролю, что бы после авторизацию пользователи делились на пулы с разными скоростями. Пытался найти в интернете конфигурацию, без успешно.Или просто дайте ссылку.
Version 3.5.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/internet_users
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl all src all
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users
#Разрешим проксируемые порты
http_access deny all
#отдельный файл для 1й группы
acl administrator proxy_auth -i "/etc/squid/group/administrator.txt"
#отдельный файл для 2й группы
acl favorit_users proxy_auth -i "/etc/squid/group/favorit_users.txt"
#отдельный файл для 3й группы
acl not_favorit_users proxy_auth -i "/etc/squid/group/not_favorit_users.txt"
delay_pools 3
delay_class 1 1
delay_class 2 1
delay_class 3 1
delay_access 1 allow administrator
delay_access 1 deny all
delay_access 2 allow favorit_users
delay_access 2 deny all
delay_access 3 allow not_favorit_users
delay_access 3 deny all
delay_parameters 1 375000/375000
delay_parameters 2 250000/250000
delay_parameters 3 125000/125000
http_port 8080
```

Создание пользователей

```
htpasswd /etc/squid/internet_users test
```

ещё нужно будет добавить в файлы логин!